# Excel vba: Finding pair of boolean values in range row by row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search, find

I'm trying to solve a rather basic question in a excel sheet using vba but I can't find the answer...

I am working on a timetable which is dynamically populated from an other excel sheet with boolean values True or False. 
The named range is called "A" in excel and contains boolean values True or False. Every column represents a possible start hour. Every row represents a different collage with a starting hour and an end hour. Each row can have NO values (entire row = False = collage is on leave)
OR the row can have two values TRUE on different cells in the same row representing start hour and end hour. 
What I would like to achieve is a to find ROW by ROW  for a couple of boolean TRUE. If found the cells between the first and second True should be colored in let's say yelow.

I am able to loop in a named range finding a specific value but I'm unable to find a pair of TRUE values in a specific row. As a double check I want to be sure that the first an second TRUE MUST be on the same row. So it is impossible to color between 2 cells in a different row.

See picture :

[image]

Some advice or thought would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Open macro recorder, find "TRUE" (make sure you do it by Rows), then find next. Stop macro recorder. Then do a logic check where the row of the two values are the same. Then fill the range with yellow. This is a starting point for you. Try to replace the `selection`s in your macro with your cell references. Come and ask a new question wherever you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the info but every sheet has a new starting hour depending on week. Would macro not be too static?

Comment: Yes it is static. You need to have it in a loop after you are done with my above comment. But first things first, you need to figure out how to find consecutive values in a row and fill the range with yellow. Then you can come and ask how to put it in a loop for many rows and different sheets.

Comment: Well I guess we are not on the same page.

Comment: you could do a "brute force" technique .... go row by row ... start with "no color"  .... scan each row from left to right  .... if true then change color (none2yellow or yellow2none) .... paint cell (none or yellow) .... repeat for each cell in row

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional formatting.

Select the full range and then use the formulas below in conditional formatting.

`=COUNTIF($A1:A1,"TRUE")>1` formatted as white

`=COUNTIF($B1:B1,"TRUE")>0` formatted as yellow

The formulas count the the number of cells with "True" for the specified range.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Another way could be to add 2 columns to the right of your data and use formulas to find the start and finish times and then conditionally format based on the time headings and the 2 new values.